# Couldn't set project path to: C:\Program when build Unity with Jenkins

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, jenkins

I new to Unity and Jenkins. I want to build automatic build for my company project with Jenkins but i have error when run build. This the error log from Jenkins:

```
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Project-Build
 > git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git.exe config remote.origin.url https://github.com/my-user-account/project.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/my-user-account/project.git
 > git.exe --version # timeout=10
 > git.exe fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/my-user-account/project.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
 > git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 16d16a1ab2deb17ec18a4f3ab1b31170b534095b (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git.exe checkout -f 16d16a1ab2deb17ec18a4f3ab1b31170b534095b
Commit message: "add builder script"
 > git.exe rev-list --no-walk e272f7767978e0af084b8a49e36385f833f7c6a9 # timeout=10
Piping unity Editor.log from D:\KAIGAN
[Project-Build] $ "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Unity.exe" -quit -batchmode -projectPath C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Project-Build -executeMethod BuildScript.PerformAndroidBuild -logFile D:\Custom Folder\JENKINS_BUILD\Project

LICENSE SYSTEM [20181224 6:7:44] Next license update check is after 2018-12-24T12:47:08


LICENSE SYSTEM [20181224 6:7:44] 00330-80123-38760-AA904 != 00330-80000-00000-AA766

Built from '2017.3/release' branch; Version is '2017.3.1f1 (fc1d3344e6ea) revision 16522547'; Using compiler version '160040219'
OS: 'Windows 10  (10.0.0) 64bit' Language: 'en' Physical Memory: 8144 MB
BatchMode: 1, IsHumanControllingUs: 0, StartBugReporterOnCrash: 0, Is64bit: 1, IsPro: 0
[Package Manager] Server::Start -- Port 60900 was selected

 COMMAND LINE ARGUMENTS:
C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Unity.exe
-quit
-batchmode
-projectPath
C:\Program
Files
(x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Project-Build
-executeMethod
BuildScript.PerformAndroidBuild
-logFile
D:\Custom Folder\JENKINS_BUILD\Project
Couldn't set project path to: C:\Program

(Filename: C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime/Utilities/Argv.cpp Line: 226)


Aborting batchmode due to failure:
Couldn't set project path to: C:\Program

FATAL: Unity3d command line execution failed with status 1
Build step 'Invoke Unity3d Editor' marked build as failure
Archiving artifacts
Finished: FAILURE
```

the error says

> Couldn't set project path to: C:\Program

but i didn't get it :(

i use this buildscipt on my Unity project: [Buildscript.cs](https://gist.github.com/Jawnnypoo/366bbcc7f65e85154a15)

i use Free Unity Version.
I using Windows 10 with jenkins and unity installed.
please help me

Comment: This is because of space character in your path. Try to wrap path in quotas or build in another directory (without spaces in path).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jenkins coping with spaces in batch file arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901106/jenkins-coping-with-spaces-in-batch-file-arguments)

Comment: You'll be much happier if you choose a different directory without spaces and not under one of the protected Windows directories, like C:\build.

Comment: thank you for your help vasily.sib and Retired Ninja, that really help me a lot :)

Comment: sorry if i make duplicate question, i was very confused at that time

Answer (score 0):

The comments are correct. You'll need to cope with the spaces in your directory path. If you are using pipeline or batch script you could use something like this.

```
bat(script: "\"%ProgramFiles%\\Unity\\Hub\\Editor\\2021.3.5f1\\Editor\\Unity.exe\" any extra commands here" )
```

You might want to try the Jenkins Unity plugin. It can help manage your unity installs and where they are located. https://plugins.jenkins.io/unity3d-plugin/