# Jenkins - withCredentials file truncates path

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to reference a secret file to run with newman under a sub directory of the workspace like so:

```
String integrationFile = "src/test/postman/integration.json"
String environmentFile = "src/test/postman/environment-dev.json"
String reportFile = "integrationReport.xml"
String reportArgs = "--reporters cli,junit --reporter-junit-export ${reportFile}"

node {
    withCredentials([file(credentialsId: "${env.FILE_KEY}", variable: "FILE_PATH")]) {

        String dataFile = "${env.FILE_PATH}"

        dir('sub-dir') {
            git branch: 'master',
                credentialsId: "${config.GitHubKeyId}",
                url: 'https://github.com/xxx/repo.git'

            withEnv(["PATH=${tool 'nodejs-12.8.0'}/bin:${env.PATH}"]) {
                    try {
                        sh ("newman run \"${integrationFile}\" -e \"${environmentFile}\" --global-var \"baseUrl=${route}\" -d ${dataFile} ${reportArgs}")
                    } catch (error) {
                        throw error
                    } finally {
                        junit "${reportFile}"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I run the code above, Jenkins throws an error:

```
error: iteration data could not be loaded
  ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/jenkins_home/workspace/Platform'
```

The path looks to be truncated because when I run a pwd command before the node closure runs, the workspace should be:

```
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/Platform Management/JJob@2
```

My question is, why is Jenkins doing this? Do I need to format the variable of the secret another way? Or should I reference it differently?

- I know the file exists because in another Jenkins pipeline that does not have a sub directory (dir("")), it works fine.
- I see from the Jenkins docs about withCredentials shows that how the file is reference gets tricky when you move between directories, see here: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/

Here are the things that I've tried:

${env.FILE_PATH}

${FILE_PATH}

$FILE_PATH

(all of the above with double and single quotes around the sh command)

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok - after playing around alot more with it, I eventually added a double quote around the variable to keep the spaces. This SO helped me out: [Jenkins coping with spaces in batch file arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901106/jenkins-coping-with-spaces-in-batch-file-arguments)

In the newman command line script, I just had add double quotes within the param args, like so:

```
sh ("newman run \"${integrationFile}\" -e \"${environmentFile}\" --global-var \"baseUrl=${route}\" -d \"${dataFile}\" ${reportArgs}")
```