# Jenkins batch with spaces in variables

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, double-quotes

So I'm trying to use bat scripts to get the information I need for my pipelines.
An example of that is the line below, where "path" is a variable that contains an absolute path to a file or folder.

> String dirOutput = bat(script: "dir ${path}", returnStdout: true)

This works well, except when this path has spaces in it. At which point I will have an error.

I have found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11903788/20011929
But wasn't able to add the double quotes in the script argument.

Any idea how to add the quotes there?

Note: This has been an issue for other scripts as well, not just dir, so I would prefer to find a solution about the quotes and not specifically about the funtionality of the line.

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine if you surround the variable with escaped quotes...

An example from a Jenkins groovy script of mine where I use a batch command:

```
bat "az storage blob upload --container-name \"${params.container}\""
```

In my example, the variable is ${params.container} and I use `\"` before and after the location where the variable is inserted into the string, because a space in the variable would otherwise cause an error.